# PHP 7 - Usuário logado(AD) e nome da máquina

Tags: php, ad

Já pesquisei no ***Stackoverflow En e PT***, google e só encontrei coisas como `getenv()`, `$_SERVER['user']`,`shell_exec()` ou qualquer coisa que me retorne dados do servidor Web, nada do usuário logado no sistema.

Outra solução, nada viável, foi utilizar o `ActiveX`, que só funcionaria no IE, sem chance.

A solução até o momento que eu encontrei foi criar um `Webservice` em .Net, que só me retorna o usuário local, nada muito difícil, mas chato por ter q utilizar outra app alem da default em php, em outro servidor.

Quanto ao nome da máquina, eu já tenho o `ip` local via `$_SERVER`, mas preciso do name da máquina local mesmo rodando o dig com `shell_exec` não rola.

Então, das 2 perguntas, buscar o usuário(ad) pelo PHP imagino que realmente não tenho saida, mas e quanto a buscar o nome da máquina local?

Comment: Você quer obter o nome da máquina do cliente no lado do servidor?

Comment: N entendi.. a aplicação roda no servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Tente fazer executando o seguinte comando.

```
<?php
$hostname = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
echo $hostname;
?>
```

Testando ele aquifuncionou perfeitamente, pelo entendi o que entendi o que tu quer

[Fonte](https://www.scriptbrasil.com.br/forum/topic/180886-pegar-o-nome-do-computador/)

Comment: gethostbyaddr me retorna o IP, se eu utilizar gethostbyname tb..

Comment: Tente com echo getenv("USERNAME");

Comment: ah... se vc está rodando o servidor web local, provavelmente vai retornar tudo, até o usuário da rede rodando o shell_exec('echo %username%'), mas como o servidor é a parte, provavelmente deve ser por isso que não rola.

Comment: Se você colocar o ip dentro do gethostbyaddr? O que rola?

Comment: echo(gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));   --me.u.i.p
echo(gethostbyname($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])); --me.u.i.p